# クライアントからSAMBAの接続ができない

Tags: linux, centos, samba

お世話になります
クライアントからSAMBAの接続ができません。
どこが悪いのかご教授頂けないでしょうか？
またこれ以外どこを調べればいいでしょうか？

1,環境
サーバ:
・CENTOS6.9
・192.168.0.18(DHCPで現在このIP)
・hoge-hoge
クライアント：
・Windows10
・192.168.0.12
・CLIENT-PC
Sambaのバージョン
・Version 3.6.23-45.el6_9

2,インストール手順

```html
①ポート開放
下記を追加
 -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
②SELINUX変更
SELINUXをdisabled
vi /etc/selinux/config
SELINUX=disabled

③ホスト変更
vi /etc/hosts
192.168.0.18    hoge-hoge
を追加

④Sambaインストール
sudo yum -y samba

⑤Samba設定
mkdir /home/hoge-hoge
chmod 777 /home/hoge-hoge
vi /etc/samba/smb.conf

------------------------------

・[global]の先頭に2行追記
unix charset = UTF-8
dos charset = CP932

・workgroup変更 ( Windowsに合わせる )
workgroup = WORKGROUP

・アクセス許可するIPに変更
hosts allow = 127. 192.168.0.

・変更
security = share

・最終行に以追記
[HOGE-GOGE]#
   path = /home/hoge-hoge# 
   writable = yes# 
   guest ok = yes# 
   guest only = yes#
   create mode = 0777# 
   directory mode = 0777#
   share modes = yes


3,
①\\192.168.0.18\hoge-hogeにアクセス
→\\192.168.0.18\hoge-hogeにアクセスできません。
と表示
②クライアントからping
ping 192.168.0.18→ ok
ping CLIENT-PC→ ok
③サーバから
ping 192.168.0.12→ ok
ping CLIENT-PC→ NG

④ポート
sudo netstat -anp | grep smbd
sudo netstat -anp | grep nmbd
で
確認→問題なし

⑤クライアント側のWindowsから見えない
⑥netenum などのツールからはhoge-hogeが見えます
```

追記
testparmを実行すると

```html
testparm

Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[homes]"
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[HOGE-HOGE]"
lp_bool(yes# 書き込みOK): value is not boolean!
lp_bool(yes# ゲストユーザーOK): value is not boolean!
lp_bool(yes# 全てゲストとして扱う): value is not boolean!
WARNING: The "share modes" option is deprecated
WARNING: The security=share option is deprecated
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
        dos charset = CP932
        server string = Samba Server Version %v
        security = SHARE
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        client signing = required
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        hosts allow = 127., 192.168.0.
        cups options = raw

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        read only = No
        browseable = No

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes
        print ok = Yes
        browseable = No

[HOGE-HOGE]
        path = /home/HOGE-HOGE# 共有フォルダ指定
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
```

mount //localhost/hoge-homge /mnt
を実行すると

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

と表示されます

ログですが
    cat log.smbd

```html
[2017/12/19 12:47:07,  0] smbd/server.c:1054(main)
  smbd version 3.6.23-45.el6_9 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2017/12/19 13:19:34,  0] smbd/server.c:1054(main)
  smbd version 3.6.23-45.el6_9 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2017/12/19 13:19:34.303080,  0] param/loadparm.c:6232(lp_bool)
  lp_bool(yes# 書き込みOK): value is not boolean!
[2017/12/19 13:19:34.303475,  0] param/loadparm.c:6232(lp_bool)
  lp_bool(yes# ゲストユーザーOK): value is not boolean!
[2017/12/19 13:19:34.303724,  0] param/loadparm.c:6232(lp_bool)
  lp_bool(yes# 全てゲストとして扱う): value is not boolean!
[2017/12/19 13:28:07,  0] smbd/server.c:1054(main)
  smbd version 3.6.23-45.el6_9 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2017/12/19 13:28:07.629718,  0] param/loadparm.c:6232(lp_bool)
  lp_bool(yes# 書き込みOK): value is not boolean!
[2017/12/19 13:28:07.629789,  0] param/loadparm.c:6232(lp_bool)
  lp_bool(yes# ゲストユーザーOK): value is not boolean!
[2017/12/19 13:28:07.629860,  0] param/loadparm.c:6232(lp_bool)
  lp_bool(yes# 全てゲストとして扱う): value is not boolean!
[2017/12/19 13:38:57,  0] smbd/server.c:1054(main)
  smbd version 3.6.23-45.el6_9 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2017/12/19 13:38:57.347976,  0] param/loadparm.c:6232(lp_bool)
  lp_bool(yes# 書き込みOK): value is not boolean!
[2017/12/19 13:38:57.348345,  0] param/loadparm.c:6232(lp_bool)
  lp_bool(yes# ゲストユーザーOK): value is not boolean!
[2017/12/19 13:38:57.348603,  0] param/loadparm.c:6232(lp_bool)
  lp_bool(yes# 全てゲストとして扱う): value is not boolean!
```

cat log.nmbd

```html
[2017/12/19 12:47:07,  0] nmbd/nmbd.c:861(main)
  nmbd version 3.6.23-45.el6_9 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2017/12/19 12:47:30,  0] nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****
  Samba name server HOGE-HOGE is now a local master browser for workgroup MYGROUP on subnet 192.168.0.18
  *****
[2017/12/19 13:19:39,  0] nmbd/nmbd.c:66(terminate)
  Got SIGTERM: going down...
[2017/12/19 13:19:39,  0] nmbd/nmbd.c:861(main)
  nmbd version 3.6.23-45.el6_9 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2017/12/19 13:20:02,  0] nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****
  Samba name server HOGE-HOGE is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 192.168.0.18
  *****
[2017/12/19 13:27:11,  0] nmbd/nmbd.c:66(terminate)
  Got SIGTERM: going down...
[2017/12/19 13:28:07,  0] nmbd/nmbd.c:861(main)
  nmbd version 3.6.23-45.el6_9 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2017/12/19 13:28:31,  0] nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****
  Samba name server HOGE-HOGE is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 192.168.0.18
  *****
[2017/12/19 13:39:01,  0] nmbd/nmbd.c:66(terminate)
  Got SIGTERM: going down...
[2017/12/19 13:39:01,  0] nmbd/nmbd.c:861(main)
  nmbd version 3.6.23-45.el6_9 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2017/12/19 13:39:25,  0] nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****
  Samba name server HOGE-HOGE is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 192.168.0.18
  *****
```

追記
＃以降をとりました

```
[HOGE-HOGE]
   path = /home/hoge-hoge
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   create mode = 0777
   directory mode = 0777
   share modes = yes
```

testparmを実行すると

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[homes]"
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[hoge-hoge]"
WARNING: The "share modes" option is deprecated
WARNING: The security=share option is deprecated
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions
```

cat log.smbd

```
  smbd version 3.6.23-45.el6_9 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
```

cat log.nmbd

```
 nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****
  Samba name server HOGE-HOGE is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 192.168.0.18
  *****
```

Comment: サーバのIPアドレスをDHCPで取得しているとリブートのたびにIPが変わる可能性があり、IPが変わったら当然接続できないという現象が生じます。サーバのIPは固定しましょう

Comment: 追加で確認した内容等は「回答」ではなく、質問自体を「編集」で追記するようにしてください。

Comment: testparmの結果でも`(yes# 書き込みOK): value is not boolean!`と怒られていますが、smb.confでコメント(#)行が前後の行とくっついており、不正な記述になっていますので見直してみてください。

Comment: #を取って実行しました
value is not boolean!はすべて消えましたが
接続は出来ません。
その旨追記しました

Comment: 今端末を変えたらうまくいきました。
テストした端末はVirtualBoxを入れていたことが原因なのでしょうか？
本当にありがとうございました

Comment: 「端末を変えたら」とは元のCLIENT-PC(192.168.0.12)とは別の端末ということでしょうか。CLIENT-PCの方はどうなったのかなど情報を整理して、この質問と回答ページを見た別の人の助けになるよう、情報を残してください。

Comment: >「端末を変えたら」とは元のCLIENT-PC(192.168.0.12)
はい別のPCです。元のPCでは相変わらずつながりません
もう少し調べてみます

Comment: @WESUEK 質問文が恐ろしい量になっていて後から見た人に取って理解できない状態になっています。ログなどはスニペットにして折りたたむかして圧縮し、質問文を精査して記述を減らして見てください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その他で確認してみてもらいたいのは

そもそもsambaサービスが起動しているか
`# service smb status`

`testparm`でsmb.confのチェックをし、エラーやワーニングが出ていないか
`# testparm`

サーバ上で自分自身をSambaマウントできるか
`# mount //localhost/hoge-homge /mnt`

ログファイルの確認
`/var/log/samba/*.log`

---

なお、サーバからクライアントに対してのpingで`ping CLIENT-PC`の結果がNGなのは、/etc/hostsにクライアントのIPアドレスが記述されていないためではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
こちらでは字数制限があるので
回答にて返信させていただきました。
ご助言頂けると幸いです

Comment: @WESUEK このポストが回答として承認されていますが解決したのでしょうか。この内容では回答にならないので、ご自分で回答として結果を投稿していただけませんか。

Answer (score 0):

いくつか気になる点があります。それらを修正すると問題の一部は解消するのではないかと思われます。

１）サーバのIPアドレスをDHCPで取得しているとリブートのたびにIPが変わる可能性がありますから、固定しましょう。IPが変わったことを考慮せずに接続しようとすれば、接続できない可能性がありますから。
２）Sambaの設定のファイルで、コメントは;で始まる「行」か、#で始まる「行」です。
行の途中の#から後ろがコメントとして解釈される訳ではありません。
　lp_bool(yes# 全てゲストとして扱う)
の行で、"value is not boolean!"(値がブーリアン値(yes/no)ではない)というエラーが出ているのは、そのせいです。
　他にも、行の先頭ではない#を含む行は、全て修正が必要です。

Sambaの設定について書いてある本やWebのページを読んで基本的な書き方を習得する事を、現在の問題の解決より優先すべきと思います。